# Error: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: mediaType == 2'

Tags: ios, iphone, nspredicate, photosframework

I'm trying to use smartAlbum to generate an array of either only videos or only photos or both.
You can see my code below:

```
    PHFetchResult *collectionList = [PHCollectionList fetchMomentListsWithSubtype:PHCollectionListSubtypeMomentListCluster options:nil];
    PHFetchOptions *options = nil;
        if (self.xSelected) {
            options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %d",PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
        }
        if (self.ySelected) {
            options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %d",PHAssetMediaTypeVideo];
        }

    [collectionList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHCollectionList *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        PHFetchResult *momentsInCollection = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsInMomentList:collection options:options];
        for (id moment in momentsInCollection) {
            PHAssetCollection *castedMoment = (PHAssetCollection *)moment;
            [_smartAlbums insertObject:castedMoment atIndex:0];
        }
    }];
```

This however is constantly breaking on the first line inside the `block` and giving the following error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: mediaType == 2'`

I did a little research and found this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17498).
I'm wondering if this is an Apple bug or if its just something wrong with my code.
It seems like it worked for the people that referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089378/fetch-only-photos-of-type-phassetmediatypeimage-form-asset-collection-type-phass), which is so weird coz its basically the same thing.

Thanks in advance,
Anish

**EDIT:**
I think I found the answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014396) in Apple's Documentation. Looks like mediaType is a key only for `PHAsset` and not `PHAssetCollection`. So now I guess the question is how to get `PFAssetCollection` with only videos or only images.

Comment: Did you work out how to fetch `PHAssetCollection` with only videos or images?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get photos and videos assets array separately.

**Get All Videos**

```
func getAllVideos(completion:@escaping  (_ videoAssets : [PHAsset]?) -> Void) {
    var videoAssets : [PHAsset] = []

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate",ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
    let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
    allVideo.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, bool) in
        videoAssets.append(asset)
    }
    completion(videoAssets)
}
```

**Get All Photos**

```
func getAllPhotos(completion:@escaping  (_ photosAssets : [PHAsset]?) -> Void) {
    var photosAssets : [PHAsset] = []

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * scale
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height  * scale

    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate",ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d || (mediaSubtype & %d) != 0 && (pixelHeight != %d AND pixelWidth != %d) OR (pixelHeight != %d AND pixelWidth != %d)", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue, PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue ,screenHeight, screenWidth, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    allPhotos.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, bool) in
        photosAssets.append(asset)
    }
    completion(photosAssets)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to put **mediaType** in predicate 
In **swift 4.0** this is how i used fetchAsset() method from **Photos framework** , to get all videos from photo library.

You can also get the video from specific folder using predicate.

```
   func fetchAllVideos()
{
    //let albumName = "blah"
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    //        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    //uncomment this if you want video from custom folder
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d ", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue )

    let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
    allVideo.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, bool) in
        // videoAssets.append(asset)
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
        imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
            if asset != nil {
                let avasset = asset as! AVURLAsset
                let urlVideo = avasset.url
                print(urlVideo)

            }
        })

    }

}
```

Hope this help!!!