# PHFetchOptions() Photos Only Using PHAsset & PHAssetCollection

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, phfetchoptions, phassetcollection

I am using a chunk from Apple's sample code here:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    // Create a PHFetchResult object for each section in the table view.
    let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(allPhotosOptions)
    let smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .AlbumRegular, options: nil)

    let topLevelUserCollections = PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions(nil)

    // Store the PHFetchResult objects and localized titles for each section.
    self.sectionFetchResults = [allPhotos, smartAlbums, topLevelUserCollections]
    self.sectionLocalizedTitles = ["", NSLocalizedString("Smart Albums", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("Albums", comment: "")]

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self)
}
```

This lists all Albums successfully.

### What I Need:

I want to **only list albums with photos**, exclude videos.  Also, **exclude video's from getting listed inside of albums**, such as inside "All Photos".

What I tried:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
```

This causes to crash saying 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: mediaType == 1'

Comment: This question mentions that asset collections don't have `mediaType`s (makes sense, they can contain multiple types):  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35590640  You don't show how you apply the predicate, but I guess you'll have to filter the the collections some other way.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman So far I believe  cellForItemAtIndexPath is where I have to check and filter.

Comment: isn't that too late? haven't you already told the collection view about the unwanted non-images in `numberOfItemsInSection` at that point? I think you should filter before then.

Comment: That is true!  So that wouldn't  work..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very late answer, but in case someone like me gets here, you should use this method to retrieve a media type. In this case **PHAssetMediaType.image**

```
func fetchAssets(with mediaType: PHAssetMediaType, options: PHFetchOptions?) -> PHFetchResult<PHAsset>
```

So in Swift 5 it writes as

```
let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: allPhotosOptions)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this only fetches photos from all albums, not a particular one.

Answer (score 1):

So far it works fine to me :

```
let allAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)
let someAlbum = allAlbums.object(at: 0)
let onlyPhotoOption = PHFetchOptions()
onlyPhotoOption.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %i", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
let photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: someAlbum, options: onlyPhotoOption)
```